# Trying to show/hide an element when clicked using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to use an if/else statement to show/hide an element when an button is clicked. The problem I have is that when the code runs the element gets shown and then quickly hides again. So the code in the if block and the else bock are both executing.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="variation">
            <h2 id="btn">Show and Hide</h2>
            <div class="mainContent">
                <p>Nam tincidunt erat et purus porttitor bibendum.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script type="JavaScript">
            var $mainContent = $('.mainContent');
            var $variation = $('.variation h2');
            $mainContent.hide();
            $('#btn').click(function() {
                if ($mainContent.css('display') == 'none') {
                    $mainContent.show('fast');
                } else {
                    $mainContent.hide('fast');
                    console.log($mainContent.css('display'))
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I have tested this in chrome and firefox.

P.S

I know I could use the jQuery `toggle()` method but I rather know how to do this without it.

Comment: You can use the .is(":visible") jquery

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qmLqh4p9/

Comment: Works fine in a jsfiddle. Are you sure it's not something else in your code affecting it?

Comment: Yea I dont why its working in jsfiddle but doesn't work when I run from my own text editor.

Comment: @Lar87 the only difference is that in jsfiddle you don't specify `<script>` tags manually - and in your code the `<script>` tag has wrong `type` ;)

Comment: My bad. That still didn't fix it though :( Everytime I click the element it shows itself then quickly hides again.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong `type` in your script tag. It should be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

not:

```
<script type="JavaScript">
```

(also, in HTML5 there is no need to put the `type` attribute if it is a JavaScript, `text/javascript` is the default, so you can ommit it entirely)

*And as a bonus - because other than that `type` thing, your code should work perfectly fine, here's a bit twisted one-line-toggle-replacement ;)*

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
   $mainContent[($mainContent.is(':visible')) ? 'show' : 'hide']('fast');
}
```

Comment: Wow it turns out I had the same script in twice. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: :D That explains a lot!